# Can't delete a file after editing with JSONObject and ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using java to edit a file that contains JSON:

```
public void editApi(String path, String nameOfOldApi, API updatedApi)
    throws IOException, ParseException
{
    String apiPath = path + "\\" + updatedApi.getTeamName() + "\\";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    String updatedJsonString = gson.toJson(updatedApi);
    JSONObject jsonToBeEditted = mapper.readValue(new File(apiPath + nameOfOldApi + ".json"), JSONObject.class);
    JSONObject updatedJson = mapper.readValue(updatedJsonString, JSONObject.class);

    for (Object key : jsonToBeEditted.keySet()) {
        if (key.equals("tags") || key.equals("paths")) {
            continue;
        } else if (!jsonToBeEditted.get(key).equals(updatedJson.get(key))) {
            System.out.println(jsonToBeEditted.get(key) + "--->" + updatedJson.get(key));
            jsonToBeEditted.put(key, updatedJson.get(key));
        }
    }

    mapper.writeValue(new File(apiPath + updatedApi.getInfo().getTitle() + ".json"), jsonToBeEditted);

    if (!updatedApi.getInfo().getTitle().equals(nameOfOldApi)) {
        Files.delete(new File(apiPath + nameOfOldApi + ".json").toPath());
    }
}
```

When I run the program (which is a spring application, if that's relevant) and make a call to this, it works fine the first time. But if I try and edit that same file again, I get a FileSystemException saying the file is being used by another process. eg, if I have a file 'test.json' and I edit it to 'test edit.json', it correctly adds the new file and deletes the old file. However, if I then edit 'test edit.json' to 'test edit again.json', it throws this error:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\stackoverflow.json: The process cannot access
the file because it is being used by another process.
```

And I'm lost as to where it happens... I feel like something isn't being closed properly in the `ObjectMapper.writeValue()` call, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You have to close all the connection which is accessing that file before deleting it. E.g. close `mapper` stream

Comment: I've attempted to do that but there doesn't seem to be a way to close the mapper via it's own methods. Is there another way to close the stream?

Comment: The `ObjectMapper` is not keeping your file open, something else is. Without seeing more code, it's not possible to tell you what is doing it.

Comment: Thanks, Sean. It's good to at the very least know what it's not haha.